# How to convert date time found in EXIF meta to XSD standard?

Tags: java, datetime, xsd, exif

I'm parsing some EXIF files.

One of the meta fields is `Date/Time Original` in the format:

`2009:09:02 03:28:43`.

My application is creating some meta-object types that will be validated against a schema. My schema defines the `Date/Time Original` field as being of type `DateTime`.

How can I convert the above to the XSD DateTime using Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a SimpleDateFormat instance to parse the date you get from the file to a java.util.Date object, then you can use another SimpleDateFormat to convert to the XSD date format. It should look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat dateConverter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date d = dateParser.parse(myExifDateString);
String xsdDateString = dateConverter.format(d);
```

Comment: thanks, works well. Considering the source data has no time zone I've left it out of the conversion format (as you have done). Your example does have a few errors; no `;` on the first line; and `parser` should be `dateParser` on line 3. Also, the `T` representing Time should have single quotes around it.

Comment: you're right ;)  I was in a hurry and did not have the means to test that code. Glad I could help though :)